# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable (in google colab)

Tags: python, list, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab sheet.
Before a minute this line was working but I don't what happened now.

----> 3 rang = [num for num in range(100)]

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

This error is coming every time, I tried refreshing the page.

Comment: You probably renamed `range` to a list. I would guess you did something like `range = [1,2,3]`

Comment: Oh yes, You got it. Bro, how can I get rid of this now. I mean how can I delete that variable, I tried refreshing the page but did not work.

Comment: Just restart your notebook

Comment: `del range` can help...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you accidentally defined `range` somewhere within your code. This overwrote the built-in definition. The line may look something like `range = [1, 2, 3]`.

You should find and get rid of that line. Then, refresh your kernel to bring back the regular definition of `range`.